# Retrieving and formatting all hasMany records in column of a MySQL result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, has-many

I'm not sure if this is even possible straight from a MySQL query (without manipulating the data after), but I have been pondering on something...

Say we have one table, authors, and another books. Authors can have many books, and this is indicated by a author_id column in the books table.

Is there a way to perform a query that:

1) Retrieves a single author record, with a column name 'books' which holds an array of book records, belonging to the author.

2) The same result, but for all authors in the database.

Any input on whether this is possible or not, and any methods would be greatly appreciated!

**Update**

Here's an example of the desired output of the first query:

```
stdClass Object
(
[id] => 1
[name] => Test Author
[age] => 28
[books] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [title] => Book 1
                [id] => 1
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [title] => Book 2
                [id] => 2
            )

    )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) can do that (although I don't this would be the best way to d o it).

2) Yes, `GROUP BY` author

Comment: I don't believe GROUP_CONCAT is what I'm looking for as this concats singles rows into a string, now all records into an array of records - check my edit for an example of the desired result from the query.

Comment: You can easily turn that into an array using [`implode()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) in PHP. That's the closest you're gonna get with MySQL.

Comment: I'd only have an array of ids though - no other book information. I wasn't optimistic that I'd find a MySQL solution for this problem, and I think I may have to carry on using JOINS and filtering/restructuring the data after the query is performed. Thanks for your answers though!

Comment: @Sam, what you could do is use `CONCAT` within the `GROUP_CONCAT` to concatenate other columns onto each id separated by a different delimiter than the `GROUP_CONCAT`. Then you could explode each book on the `GROUP_CONCAT` delimiter, then explode the book's information on the `CONCAT` delimiter you set. This is a hacky way of doing things though and is not recommended.